# How to perform sql "LIKE" operation on firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase for data storage. The data structure is like this:

```
products:{
   product1:{
      name:"chocolate",
   }
   product2:{
      name:"chochocho",
   }
}
```

I want to perform an auto complete operation for this data, and normally i write the query like this:

```
"select name from PRODUCTS where productname LIKE '%" + keyword + "%'";
```

So, for my situation, for example, if user types "cho", i need to bring both "chocolate" and "chochocho" as result. I thought about bringing all data under "products" block, and then do the query at the client, but this may need a lot of memory for a big database. So, how can i perform sql LIKE operation?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a way to do it with firebase ?

Comment: @FaridAlHaddad it's been so long since I asked this question, I do not even remember asking it but it looks like I probably have not found a solution and decided to do something else.

Comment: haha .. and what was the solution ? Can you share it please ? Thanks

Comment: @FaridAlHaddad I really do not remember, but it looks like a lot of people are looking for an answer to this question and so I will search again this topic and post If I find something useful.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: Is there any solution for this question? Thanks

Comment: Have you rated this library? https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/jsayol/firesql/

Answer (score 32):

**Update: With the release of Cloud Functions for Firebase, there's another elegant way to do this as well by [linking Firebase to Algolia via Functions](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fulltext-search).** The tradeoff here is that the Functions/Algolia is pretty much zero maintenance, but probably at increased cost over roll-your-own in Node.

There are no content searches in Firebase at present. Many of the more common search scenarios, such as searching by attribute will be baked into Firebase as the API continues to expand.

In the meantime, it's certainly possible to grow your own. However, searching is a vast topic (think creating a real-time data store vast), greatly underestimated, and a critical feature of your application--not one you want to ad hoc or even depend on someone like Firebase to provide on your behalf. So it's typically simpler to employ a scalable third party tool to handle indexing, searching, tag/pattern matching, fuzzy logic, weighted rankings, et al.

The Firebase blog features a [blog post on indexing with ElasticSearch](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-01-02-queries-part-two.html) which outlines a straightforward approach to integrating a quick, but extremely powerful, search engine into your Firebase backend.

Essentially, it's done in two steps. Monitor the data and index it:

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var ElasticClient = require('elasticsearchclient')

// initialize our ElasticSearch API
var client = new ElasticClient({ host: 'localhost', port: 9200 });

// listen for changes to Firebase data
var fb = new Firebase('<INSTANCE>.firebaseio.com/widgets');
fb.on('child_added',   createOrUpdateIndex);
fb.on('child_changed', createOrUpdateIndex);
fb.on('child_removed', removeIndex);

function createOrUpdateIndex(snap) {
   client.index(this.index, this.type, snap.val(), snap.name())
     .on('data', function(data) { console.log('indexed ', snap.name()); })
     .on('error', function(err) { /* handle errors */ });
}

function removeIndex(snap) {
   client.deleteDocument(this.index, this.type, snap.name(), function(error, data) {
      if( error ) console.error('failed to delete', snap.name(), error);
      else console.log('deleted', snap.name());
   });
}
```

Query the index when you want to do a search:

```
<script src="elastic.min.js"></script>
 <script src="elastic-jquery-client.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    ejs.client = ejs.jQueryClient('http://localhost:9200');
    client.search({
      index: 'firebase',
      type: 'widget',
      body: ejs.Request().query(ejs.MatchQuery('title', 'foo'))
    }, function (error, response) {
       // handle response
    });
 </script>
```

[There's an example, and a third party lib to simplify integration, here.](http://firebase.github.io/flashlight/)

Comment: ah thank you, but i am actually using firebase for my android app, and i have little javascript knowledge. Can you give me a link or a little example like this javascript example that is written as a java code? I will also try to understand that javascript code now :) Thanks

Comment: Is this still relevant in 2016?

Comment: Conceptually relevant. The syntax of the API calls is slightly different.

Comment: Hi Kato, I've posted a question here about doing the flashlight setup with the new Firebase, and was hoping you could provide some of your knowledge! I would really appreciate it, thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276209/setting-up-flashlight-on-heroku-for-elasticsearch-with-new-firebase

Comment: @Kato to use elastic search means one need a heroku account which is a chargeable service

Comment: Heroku is a drop in an ocean of possible hosting services, some of which are [completely free](https://www.openshift.com/pricing/index.html). But yes, integrating with third party services does mean some legwork.

Comment: Sadly, you have to upgrade to the Blaze Plan to use Firebase Cloud Functions with Algolia

Comment: Hi @Kato AL here. I've been trying out the [sample integration provided](http://firebase.github.io/flashlight/) but I can't seem to retrieve any results (although it does show a *query used*). An example search query I tried is `*ninja*`, user is ticked. Was expecting to see at least `ninjai` user to be returned. Is the sample still functional? All the best!

Comment: Also, as I understand how ElasticSearch works, every time a new data is added (e.g. title, description), it would be detected and will be indexed in Firebase -- and from the little details I know about RTDB, indexing is related to the Firebase DB rules -- is the ElasticSearch solution better for record searching (against the Algolia solution)? (*I'm working on something with Android if that also changes some things*). Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 21):

I believe you can do :

```
admin
.database()
.ref('/vals')
.orderByChild('name')
.startAt('cho')
.endAt("cho\uf8ff")
.once('value')
.then(c => res.send(c.val()));
```

this will find vals whose name are starting with cho.

[source](https://youtu.be/sKFLI5FOOHs?t=5m52s)

Comment: Per my understanding startAt() and endAt() is for limiting results between two specific objects in database - not to query content of the string.

Comment: @Heisenbug it works, the source video is from google itself.

Comment: this helped me building a small search feature. I created an index of each words, linking each of them to the related item. Then, when searching, I count hits on each item.

Comment: @Heisenbug see ^

Comment: @Ced Is there any way to get names that **contain** cho, not only start with them (qwerty**cho**, ab**cho**ba)?

Comment: This works, thanks! Hopefully there's a more "native" solution in the pipeline from the Firebase devs.

Answer (score 1):

The elastic search solution basically binds to add set del and offers a get by wich you can accomplish text searches.
It then saves the contents in mongodb.

While I love and reccomand elastic search for the maturity of the project, the same can be done without another server, using only the firebase database.
That's what I mean:
(https://github.com/metaschema/oxyzen)

for the indexing part basically the function:

1. JSON stringifies a document.
2. removes all the property names and JSON to leave only the data
   (regex).
3. removes all xml tags (therefore also html) and attributes (remember
   old guidance, "data should not be in xml attributes") to leave only
   the pure text if xml or html was present.
4. removes all special chars and substitute with space (regex)
5. substitutes all instances of multiple spaces with one space (regex)
6. splits to spaces and cycles:
7. for each word adds refs to the document in some index structure in
   your db tha basically contains childs named with words with childs
   named with an escaped version of "ref/inthedatabase/dockey"
8. then inserts the document as a normal firebase application would do

in the oxyzen implementation, subsequent updates of the document ACTUALLY reads the index and updates it, removing the words that don't match anymore, and adding the new ones.

subsequent searches of words can directly find documents in the words child. multiple words searches are implemented using hits

Answer (score 1):

SQL"LIKE" operation on firebase is possible

```
let node = await db.ref('yourPath').orderByChild('yourKey').startAt('!').endAt('SUBSTRING\uf8ff').once('value');
```

Comment: Don't use this suggestion if the database is large. After executing this request, my database stopped working and did not send a response for about 5 minutes from different devices. Perhaps this issue related to firebase database logic.

Answer (score -4):

This query work for me, it look like the below statement in MySQL

`select * from StoreAds where University Like %ps%;`

`query =  database.getReference().child("StoreAds").orderByChild("University").startAt("ps").endAt("\uf8ff");`

Comment: This does not work correctly, run more tests and you will see.