# Firebase query - Find item with child that contains string

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, database, firebase

I'm having a bit of trouble with a Firebase Query. I want to query for objects, where the objects child value contains a certain string. So far I have something that looks like this:

```
Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs"];
[[[[ref queryOrderedByKey] queryStartingAtValue:@"b"] queryEndingAtValue:@"b~"]
    observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    NSLog(@"%@", snapshot.key);
}];
```

But that only gives objects that have a starting value of "b". I want objects that contains the string "b". How do I do that?

Comment: See also [[1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034860/firebase-how-to-match-opponents-in-a-game/25039133#25039133)] [[2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510007/firebase-get-all-data-that-contains/22522896#22522896)] [[3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559191/firebase-and-indexing-search)] [[4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812624/firebase-where-like-search)] [[5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506531/how-to-perform-sql-like-operation-on-firebase/22522874#22522874)]

Answer (score 12):

There are no contains or fuzzy matching methods in the query API, which you have probably already guessed if you've scanned [the API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/api/) and [the guide on queries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries).

Not only has this subject been discussed ad nauseam on SO [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034860/firebase-how-to-match-opponents-in-a-game/25039133#25039133)] [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510007/firebase-get-all-data-that-contains/22522896#22522896)] [[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559191/firebase-and-indexing-search)] [[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812624/firebase-where-like-search)] [[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506531/how-to-perform-sql-like-operation-on-firebase/22522874#22522874)], but I've touched several times on why one should [use a real search engine](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-01-02-queries-part-two.html), instead of attempting this sort of half-hearted search approach.

There is a reason it's often easier to Google a website to find results than to use the built-in search, and this is a primary component of that failure.

With all of that said, the answer to your question of how to do this manually, since there is no built-in contains, is to set up a server-side process that loads/streams data into memory and does manual searching of the contents, preferably with some sort of caching.

But honestly, ElasticSearch is faster and simpler, and more efficient here. Since that's a vast topic, I'll defer you to the [blog post on this subject](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-01-02-queries-part-two.html).