# Firebase database query by user name

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My DB looks like this :

[image]

In my app, I have a search bar, at the time the user search I want to find all the users with the same name or starting with the same text.

So what I did was :

```
func seachUser(named : String){
    usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "userName")
    .queryStarting(atValue: named)
    .observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snap) in
                print(snap.value)
    }
}
```

But, each time I get all the list of the users.
How can I fix it?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your querying for a so-called open-ended range. I.e. if `named` is `Jo`, then you'll get all results starting with `Jone` and then every child node after that.

To only get user names starting with `Jo`, you'll want to close the range by adding `queryEnding(atValue:`. The trick here is to end at the last known character that you want, for which we typically use the highest known unicode character:

```
func seachUser(named : String){
    usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "userName")
    .queryStarting(atValue: named)
    .queryEnding(atValue: named+"\uf8ff")
    .observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snap) in
                print(snap.value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks!
But there is still a problem, for example, if I want to search the name "Frank" and I send the string "rank" I get no result. how can I fix that? thanks

Comment: That is a different search, which is not possible with the built-in operations of the Firebase Database. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589092/firebase-query-find-item-with-child-that-contains-string

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be helpful.

```
usersRef.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "userName").queryEqual(toValue: "userName like for ex Jone").observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.value is NSNull {
       return
    }else{
        for item in snapshot.children {
            print(snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject])
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `״queryEqual״` will find only the exact same username