# Firebase observe key contains

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'd like to fetch snapshot which contains typed text. For example node look like this

```
"Team": {
 "Yankees": {
    "uid1": "name",
    "uid2": "name"
   },
"Angels": {
   "uid1": "name"
   "uid3": "name"
 }
```

and if user typed `yan` in search bar then I want to fetch "Yankees" snapshot. I saw some document and stack over flow post and tried like so

`ref.child("Team").queryStarting(atValue: "yan").queryEnding(atValue: "yan\u{f8ff}").observe`

but it doesn't work. How can I do this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase searches are case sensitive. Since your key starts with an uppercase `Y`, the query only matches if it also does that:

```
ref.child("Team")
   .queryOrderedByKey()
   .queryStarting(atValue: "Yan")
   .queryEnding(atValue: "Yan\u{f8ff}").observe
```

I also `queryOrderedByKey()` to be explicit about what you want to order/filter on.

If you want to allow case-insensitive filtering, the typical approach is to add a property with the all-lowercase value to each team:

```
"Team": {
 "Yankees": {
    "teamNameForSearch": "yankees",
    "uid1": "name",
    "uid2": "name"
   },
"Angels": {
    "teamNameForSearch": "angels",
   "uid1": "name"
   "uid3": "name"
 }
```

Now you can search with:

```
ref.child("Team")
   .queryOrdered(byChild: "teamNameForSearch")
   .queryStarting(atValue: "yan")
   .queryEnding(atValue: "yan\u{f8ff}").observe
```

A final note is that both approaches only do so-called *prefix matches*: they find teams whose name *starts* with what the user typed. If you want a *contains* operation (as the title of your question suggests), you will have to look beyond Firebase for a solution. For more on that, see Kato's answer here: [Firebase query - Find item with child that contains string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589092/firebase-query-find-item-with-child-that-contains-string)

Comment: Thank you Frank that's really helpful!! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the db to this:

```
"Team": {
"randomid": {
"team":"Yankees",
"uid1": "name",
"uid2": "name"
},
"randomid": {
 "team":"Angels"
 "uid1": "name"
 "uid3": "name"
}
```

and now you can do this:

```
ref.child("Team").queryOrdered(byChild: "team").queryStarting(atValue: "Yan").queryEnding(atValue: "Yan\u{f8ff}").observe
```

First in your query above, you need to use `queryOrdered()` to know which child you want to order.

Also in your database the node `Team` is not equal to anything, it is a parent node that has child nodes.

So to fix this, the node `Team` needs to be equal to a value(like in the database in this answer) so you will be able to order it and use queryStarting and queryEnding on it.

Comment: Thank you Peter that's really cool approach!! I will take advantage of this:)