# Use firebase realtime database create search function

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I would like to create a search feature for my apps by using firebase real time database, which similar to facebook search.

I did some research and acknowledge that firebase real time is not able to search with "text contain". But i believe there must be some method to achieve it, like combine startAt or endAt.

I need some advise the best practice to do it.

The DB structure will look like:

```
Restaurant
-->RandomID
---->name: 'Good Restaurant'
---->address:
---->desc:
-->RandomID
---->name: 'Dixon Lee Restaurant'
---->address:
---->desc:
-->RandomID
---->name: 'MCD'
---->address:
---->desc:
```

**Edited**
I not sure how the startAt and endAt work. Is it supposes to return 3 and above if i use startAt(3)? What if i use startAt with string? Like below problem i ecnounter:

```
firebase.database().ref('/restaurants').orderByChild('name').startAt('Good').on('value',snap=>{
      console.log(snap.val())
    })
```

The above query will return:
[image]

I am thinking to achieve "text contains" with startAt/endAt, which will find specific value of field that begin/end with a keyword. Not sure is this the usage for startAt/endAt.

Comment: Since you've already found answers about it, what specific do you think is possible and how it fits with those other answers? Otherwise I'm not sure what to answer or how it's different from the existing answers (which are quite plentiful).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for always responding to the firebase question. I have problem with the usage of startAt and endAt, the documentation doesn't clear enough to guide a rookie like me.. I have updated the post with the problem i encountered.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be confusing `startAt` with a function that would accepts strings that start **with** a certain value. That's simply not how Firebase filtering work.

When you do `ref('/restaurants').orderByChild('name').startAt('Good')`, it does three things:

1. Orders all child nodes of `restaurants` on their `name` value.
2. Find the first one starting with `Good` (or anything lexicographically after `Good`)
3. Returns every child from there on

So you're getting the child nodes with name `Good Restaurant` and `MCD`.

You can use `startAt` and `endAt` to return a **range** of child nodes, i.e. all the ones starting *with* `Good`. To do this you create a range starting at `Good` and ending at `Good\uF8FF`:

```
ref('/restaurants').orderByChild('name').startAt('Good').endAt('Good\uF7FF')
```

Since `\uF8FF` is the last known Unicode character, this query returns items starting with e.g. `Good`, `Goodie`, `Goodness`, but not `Gooey` (since `Gooe` is after `Good\uF7FF`).

Comment: Thanks for explaining, i not sure am i understand and i also not sure how to ask further... orderByChild('name') will make all my restaurant list according “name" property from A to Z, and startAt('Good') will return all the restaurant (as an object) that after "G"? If i have "Fun", "Happy", "Better", "Crazy" and "Inspire" Restaurant, it will return Fun, Happy, Inspire Restaurant to me? Furthermore, i don't understand how endAt work and what does \uF8FF mean. I googled it, they say is "last" but i not sure how it work with endAt

Comment: If you order  "Fun", "Happy", "Better", "Crazy" and "Inspire" alphabetically, you get "Better", "Crazy", "Fun", "Happy", "Inspire". If you then start at "Good" (so drop everything before "Good") you will get "Happy", and "Inspire". If you start at "Good" and end at "Hollow", you will only get "Happy".

Comment: Lets say i order "Fun Restaurant", "Happy Cafe", "Better Restaurant", "Crazy cafe", "Good Restaurant" and "Inspire Coffee Shop" alphabetically, i will get "Better Restaurant", "Crazy cafe", "Fun Restaurant", "Good Restaurant" ,"Happy Cafe" and "Inspire Coffee Shop" right? How do i get "Better Restaurant", "Fun Restaurant" and "Good Restaurant" by querying "Restaurant"? or get "Inspire Coffee Shop" by querying Coffee or Shop? Is that even possible? or is firestore able to achieve it? Thanks again!

Comment: That's a query for a substring, which isn't possible with Firebase database queries. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589092/firebase-query-find-item-with-child-that-contains-string

Answer (score 3):

For full text search with Firebase you you are better off using Algolia, as recomended in the  [full-text search](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search#solution_algolia) page in the official Firebase documentation. Here is an easy to follow tutorial for Realtime Database:

[Firebase Algolia Tutorial](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/sending-and-managing-data/send-and-update-your-data/tutorials/firebase-algolia/)

It is free to use if you have less then 10k records.