# Check if value includes on firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can check in the firebase if value exist by using this function:

```
  ref.child("users").orderByChild("id")
  .equalTo("string").once("value",snapshot => {
      if (snapshot.exists()){
         //exist
      }
   })
```

But my question is, can I do like `includes` function do? For exemple, I want to check if a part of my `string` exist on firebase. I would like to check if there is `id` that includes `str` for exemple. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Firebase Realtime Database queries can do prefix matches (looking for values that *start with* a certain string), but can't check if a value *contains* a string. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589092/firebase-query-find-item-with-child-that-contains-string and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506531/how-to-perform-sql-like-operation-on-firebase

Comment: Ok thanks, gonna check for other database options