# Firebase query results are mistaken

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my database design.

```
foodie-ab2b4{
 Foods{
   0{
    FoodName: "Baked Beans In Tomato Sauce"
    FoodRecipe: 
    FoodUri: 
    Image: 
    }
   1{
    FoodName: "Another bean | Bubbling Bacon Butter Beans recipes"
    FoodRecipe: 
    FoodUri: 
    Image: 
    }
   }
  }
```

I'm working on an ios project and this is how my firebase json structured.

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
func searchFoodByName(FoodName: String){
    let foodsRef = ref.child("Foods")

    let input = FoodName
    let query = foodsRef.child(key).queryOrdered(byChild: "FoodName").queryEnding(atValue: input)
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot)
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
            let fName = dict["FoodName"] as! String
            let fIngredients = dict["Ingredients"] as! [String]
            print(fName)
            print(fIngredients)

            let key = snapshot.key
            print(key)
        }
    })    
}
```

I'm trying to filter my food objects by their names. I have 10 objects in my database. In most cases this search return true objects. But there is one example i can not solve.

When i query the "tomato" word i need to get 1 object. But there is two. Although there is no tomato word in my second object.

The two object is in my json file.

If it is necessary i can upload my whole JSON file to here.

Comment: What is the value of `key`?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to assume that Firebase can filter based on strings that **contain** a value, but it can't. See [Firebase query - Find item with child that contains string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589092/firebase-query-find-item-with-child-that-contains-string) (and the many links from there).

What Firebase *can* do is search for string values that **start with** a certain value. You do that by using a combination of `queryStarting(atValue:)` and `queryEnding(atValue:)`:

```
let query = foodsRef
  .queryOrdered(byChild: "FoodName")
  .queryStarting(atValue: input)
  .queryEnding(atValue: input+"\\uf8ff")
```

If you use this query, and `input` is ``Baked`, it will only match the first food from your JSON.