# Firebase query search string for a word

Tags: node.js, string, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, filter

In firebase, how can one go about running a query to find matches which have a specific word in the string?

for example querying all descriptions that have the word happy in them.

I am able to do this with JS but that means I have to load the entire DB which is over 300 items...

Cheers!

Comment: Server-side queries can filter for strings that *start with* a certain substring, but can't search for strings that *contain* a certain substring. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589092/firebase-query-find-item-with-child-that-contains-string

Comment: Darn, this is a shame... So my only option would be downloading the whole node then query with JS? Anything you may recommend?

Comment: If you want full-text search, I'd set up a full-text search solution (ElasticSearch, Algolia, etc). Firebase Realtime Database is more focused on realtime data synchronization.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to download the entire DB for this (i assume you'r using realtime database over firestore).

You can filter your data mixing `orderByChild()` or `orderByKey()` or  `orderByValue()` with query methods like `startAt()`, `endAt()` and `equalTo()`.

For example, if your list of nodes url is 
`https://mydb-xxxx.firebaseio.com/parentnode/childnodeslist`

You can query in this way:

```
// Find all nodes whose property myString is "hello"

var ref = firebase.database().ref("parentnode/childnodeslist");
ref.orderByChild("myString").equalTo('hello').once(‘value’).then(function(element){
  console.log(element);
});
```

[see the query doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query) and [how to structure your data in firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data)

**EDIT: BASED ON COMMENTS:**

If you want to make a full text search you can:

*1)* Make it client side

```
// assume "myString" is your param name

var word = 'hello';
var listOfItems = [];
firebase.database().ref("parentnode/childnodeslist").then(function(list){
  listOfItems = list.map(function(item){
    if( item.myString.indexOf(word) >= 0){
      return {id: item.id, word: item.myString}
    }
  })
})
```

*2)* Use a third party tools like ElasticSearch (as suggested by @Frank-van-Puffelen) or [Algolia](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search)

*3)* Use Cloud Functions

Comment: Hi emanuele. I'm aware of this type of querying, my problem is that 'hello' could be the third/fourth/tenth word in the string. I need to query that specific word and return all paragraphs that contain that word.

Comment: Is not a problem how deeper is your final node

Comment: It is only 3 deep

Comment: You can use `ref('one/two/three')`  then query the param name `orderByChild('param')` with the string you want `equalTo('string')`

Comment: I dont think you're understanding my question clearly. I am not looking for a one worded string, I am trying to return all paragraphs with a specific string in it which could be a word in the middle of that paragraph... does that make sense? so equalTo('bob') would not make sense if i was trying to return a paragraph like, "hi there my name is **bob** and i like pizza". I need to return all pargraphs in that node with the word bob in it, not single worded strings that === bob.

Comment: I've add more examples. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks emanuele! So **#1** is what I was initially doing, this requires the whole node to be downloaded if i'm not mistaken which is not a good idea in my case because rather than a search input its buttons the user presses with a single string value (could be quick and lots of downloads). option **#2** elastic search seems too heavy for my needs (if it was ecommerce type of application with the text search I would be more open to it. I'd like to hear more about your **#3** if you dont mind. I am using cloud functions for a couple things but dont see how this would be possible in cloud funcs

Comment: @hugger in cloud function you can create a REST API so you can get a string client side and search whatever you want in your database then return a list of results

Comment: this would be bad for a large section of nodes, ie usernames ```firebase.database().ref("parentnode/childnodeslist").``` better to filter before downloading