# Error: Query: First argument passed to equalTo() cannot be an object. Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have this node where preferences is an object: 
[image]

I would create a query: I would get only users that they have cinema as a preference. I try this code:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://event-application.firebaseio.com/users"); 
$scope.pref = "Cinema"
var user = $firebaseArray(ref.orderByChild("preferences").equalTo($scope.pref));
```

But i get this problem: `angular.js:12416 Error: Query: First argument passed to startAt(), endAt(), or equalTo() cannot be an object.`
How can i fix it please.

Comment: So how about `.equalTo("Cinema")`?

Comment: But aside from that, you can search nested queries like this. Either store `/user/$uid/preferences/Cinema = true` and query `ref.child('users').orderByChild('preferences/Cinema').equalTo(true)` or (more likely) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510007/firebase-get-all-data-that-contains

Comment: when i put   `.equalTo("Cinema")` i get an error :  ` ref1.orderByChild(...).equelTo is not a function`. My problem is how to pass an object in the query

Comment: `equelTo` -> `equalTo`

Comment: How ?? i change equalTo by equelTo!!