# How to search for a value in firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am saving data as follows in the Firebase:

[image: structure]

I want to find all records that have #Yahoo in their title. What will be the exact query for that?

I am confused with the random key created. I am not sure how to handle this so i am posting it here.

```
Firebase firebase = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL_USER_TASKS).child(Utils.encodeEmail(unProcessedEmail));
        Query queryRef = firebase.orderByKey().startAt("#" + mHashTag).endAt("#" + mHashTag + "\uf8ff");

        queryRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mTasksList.clear();
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                for (DataSnapshot task : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    mTasksList.add(task.getValue(TaskModel.class));
                }
                mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, mTasksList.size());
                mSwipeToRefresh.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mSwipeToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                mSwipeToRefresh.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mSwipeToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 19):

You cannot search for any item whose title *contains* `#Yahoo`. See:
 [How to perform sql "LIKE" operation on firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506531/how-to-perform-sql-like-operation-on-firebase)

You can however search items whose title *begins with* `#Yahoo`:

```
Firebase firebase = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL_USER_TASKS).child(Utils.encodeEmail(unProcessedEmail));

Query queryRef = firebase.orderByChild("title").startAt("#" + mHashTag)
```

To make this work well, you have to add an [index to your Firebase rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/indexing-data.html):

```
"rules": {
  "userTasks": {
    "$email": {
      ".indexOn": "title" // index tasks in their title property
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can i achieve that after changing the structure of the database?

Comment: I am also maintaining the task IDs in the HashTag tree, as the list. But is it possible to get only the tasks with their IDs?

Comment: The code above will filter the tasks by their title.

Comment: Thanks for that but it will give items whose title begins with #Yahoo. That is not required, #Tag can be anywhere.

Comment: As said in my answer: Firebase cannot do a query for strings that *contain* a specific value. If that is what you are looking for, I'll find a duplicate.

Comment: As i said i am also maintaining the task IDs in the HashTag tree as the list. For example in this image http://imgur.com/y6q2QRR i am showing the structure of the Hash Tag. You can see the taskKeys node, I will store all the Task keys in it. Can i get all the task details in one query? Or should i loop through to get them?

Comment: Could you explain further (the docs at firebase.google.com about Indexing  weren't too clear) what this does and if this is mandatory?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen are you able to make it non-case sensitive?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38590937/firebase-query-methods-startat-taking-case-sensitive-parameters

Answer (score 6):

This is working with the Google Firebase.

```
DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("userTasks").orderByChild("title").equalTo("#Yahoo");
    query.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);

ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            //TODO get the data here

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
    {

    }
};
```

Comment: This only works for exact queries supplied by the user that matches data. This is not a suitable way to provide search to users, they need a 'like' element.

Comment: @edwoollard, What is the solution for providing 'like' search?

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal This one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40633692/4409113 Maybe?

Answer (score 4):

```
    DatabaseReference mDatabase =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("userTasks");
    mDatabase.orderByChild("title").equalTo("#Yahoo").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
       ///Here you can get all data 
    }
    @Override
     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer : simply do following query :

```
databaseReference.orderByChild('_searchLastName')
 .startAt(queryText)
 .endAt(queryText+"\uf8ff");
```

We can combine startAt and endAt to limit both ends of our query. The following example finds all dinosaurs whose name starts with the letter `b`:

```
curl 'https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs.json?orderBy="$key"&startAt="b"&endAt="b\uf8ff"&print=pretty'
```

The `\uf8ff` character used in the query above is a very high code point in the Unicode range. Because it is after most regular characters in Unicode, the query matches all values that start with a `b`.

Here's a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40633692/4409113) and the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#range-queries).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("userTasks");

  Query query=mDatabaseRef.orderByChild("title").equalTo("#Yahoo");

    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot data:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


                Records models=data.getValue(Records.class);
                String latitude=models.getLatitude();
                String longitude=models.getLongitude();

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I have declared only two strings here, latitude and longitude. If you want to load more values you need to add that also.

Then create a new class Records as follows

```
public class Records {

public String latitude,longitude;

public Records()
{

}

public String getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public String getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but this solution worked for me.

```
 getContentResolver().delete(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA + "=?" , new String[]{ paths.get(i) });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference animalsRef = rootRef.child("userTasks");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Boolean found;
        String search = "Yahoo";
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String movieName = ds.child("movieName").getValue(String.class);
            found = movieName.contains(search);
            Log.d("TAG", movieName + " / " + found);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
animalsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```