# How to Search for data in Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: FireBase Database image]

I want to search a condition if user says MSCS,then Search should check 
-> condition that MSCS is equal to 1 then get all the data like SJSU(University Name) and CA (City Name) in my Android Application show as a Listview/Fragmentview.

I tried [How to search for a value in firebase Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537369/how-to-search-for-a-value-in-firebase-android)   but I'm unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds that you are looking for something like the following.

```
mDatabase.orderByChild("MSCS").equalTo(1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
    new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //data will be available on dataSnapshot.getValue();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
});
```

Let me know if this works for you :)

Comment: Actually I'm planning a search where user select MSCS..and university name has to shown in the Listview . I'm bit confused with onDataChange method how it can be useful

Comment: @user2536273 what do you mean user select the MSCS? you can search for whatever MSCS you want by using `equalTo(MSCSValue)`. `onDataChange` is a callback that will be called with a snapshot of the data at this location. It will also be called each time that data changes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43733318/how-to-search-and-fetch-perticuler-data-from-firebase-database

Answer (score 3):

Firebase equalTo(String value) method only returns value if it matches exactly. It is not like SQL LIKE query

Comment: So what do we need to do to achieve an 'SQL LIKE', feature?