# Android- How to perform search on Firebase database (e.g. MATCH and LIKE of sql)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Android- How to perform search (e.g. MATCH and LIKE of sql) on Firebase's whole database to get data. I want exact coding.

Comment: I think this should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928163/how-to-search-for-data-in-firebase-android

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559191/firebase-and-indexing-search

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ur link shows just theory I want coding for android so better you do not mark it as duplicate.

Comment: Nobody is going to do the coding for you. If you're having concrete problems implementing the approaches in the links, post the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).