# Firebase Database Query Android

Tags: android, search, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have done some research on Firebase database query for Android. But I still could not find the way to do searching for a substring of a string. For example, I want to search for "def" in "abcdefghijkl". How supposed can I get that by using startAt() and endAt() or there is another way to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for strings using

```
databaseReference.orderByChild('_searchLastName')
             .startAt(queryText)
             .endAt(queryText+"\uf8ff")
             .once("value")
```

[How to do a simple search in string in Firebase database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618953/how-to-do-a-simple-search-in-string-in-firebase-database)