# How to search in firebase database?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'd like to make a search bar, and if I get the search word, I'd like to get the data which include the word on firebase.

I've already implimented a search bar and am looking for what I have to write in `func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)`.

So far, I have an idea. 
It uses "for" and "if" to run code like this to get data.

```
for i in (~) {
    let defaultPlace = DBRef.child("posts/\(i)/age")
    defaultPlace.observe(.value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in 
        if ~ {
            self.displayAge.text = (snap.value! as AnyObject).description
        }
    }
}
```

(↑ this is just an example. "~" is something)

But I'm not sure if it's really the best way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618953/how-to-do-a-simple-search-in-string-in-firebase-database Although it is for android you could apply it for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

iOS:

`queryOrdered(byChild: "{field name}").queryStarting(atValue: "{value}")`

replace {field name} and {value}

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is maybe an elementary question, but what is  {field name}? And should I input a search word to  {value}?

Comment: `field name` is the field you want to search for. `value` is text of user input in search bar

Comment: Thank you! But if I write let result = DBRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "title").queryStarting(atValue: searchtext)
        print(result), it returns only (/ {
    i = tite;
    sp = "\U9752";
}). Is this wrong?