# AngularFire2 orderByKey and startAt

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have the following Database structure:

```
{
 "users" : {
    "ap1-AXLKSD9ASLKDJJ0991" : {
      "enabled" : true,
      "color" : "red"
    },
    "ap1-A778ASDUASDJ8AS8DA" : {
      "enabled" : true,
      "color" : "blue"
    },
    "ap2-ASD88ASD8ASD8HAS8D" : {
      "enabled" : true,
      "color" : "red"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get all users who have a key starting with "ap1-" as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {
    //
    // Database
    userList: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

    public constructor(
        public afDb: AngularFireDatabase) {
    }

    getUsers() {
        return this.userList = this.afDb.list('/users', {
            preserveSnapshot: true,
            query: {
                orderByKey: true,
                startAt: 'ap1-'
            }
         });
    }
}
```

The above code however, returns ap1- and ap2- keys. I'm searched online and cannot find any way to achieve this.

I tried with equalTo.. when I put in the exact correct key, it finds only this. When I put in a nonsense key it finds nothing.

It seems like there's a bug in startAt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it with firebase like that. What 'startsWith' does is to retrieve all the keys from 'ap1-' and above, not the strings that have 'ap1-' as first characters.

If you had an the following keys

```
{"1", "2", "3", "4"}
```

and queried it like

```
startsWith: "3"
```

then you would get

```
{ "3", "4" }
```

Comment: Ok, so how would I be able to achieve the outcome? There has to be a way to find all keys that start with or contain a specific string?

Comment: If the search will always be the same you can have a new value on every object, like:  `"ap1-A778ASDUASDJ8AS8DA" : {
      "enabled" : true,
      "color" : "blue", searchPattern: "ap1"
    },` and then use `query: {
                orderByChild: searchPattern,
                equalsTo: 'ap1'
            }`

Comment: Or try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618953/how-to-do-a-simple-search-in-string-in-firebase-database