# Firebase querying with partial string match

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Suppose I have a simple firebase realtime database structure where the key is `username` and the value is `userid`. Now I want to search `userid` by `username`. It is quite easy if the username matches. but how to get the answer for partial match. To be more clear if i were to write this using SQL it would be something like:

`SELECT userid 
FROM tablename 
WHERE username LIKE 'abc%'`

it will give me all the `userid` where the `username` starts with `abc`. 
How to write this type of query for firebase? Understand i am using this on a android device and there can be a lot of user.

Comment: Please check my answer out and see if it's working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618953/how-to-do-a-simple-search-in-string-in-firebase-database check this link

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the doc of Java Admin you can do something like this it should also work with Android

For data starting with `abc`,

```
yourRef.orderByKey().startAt("abc").endAt("abc\uf8ff")
```

The \uf8ff is after most regular characters in Unicode, so the query should matches all values that start with a `abc`.

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks. But can you explain "\uf8ff" a little more.  Also will it return a array of userid ?

Comment: As I've explain that `\uf8ff is after most regular characters in Unicode` and It will return `Query` object in Firebase you can get data by `attaching` `ValueEventListener`. Then get data from datasnapshot.