# dart: get SQL like "%text%" search from firebase database snapshot

Tags: android, string, dart, flutter

i am currently working on a search function in my app. this gets a reference of my firebase database snapshot. im using the firebaseDatabase package for this.

currently im using this to search my database

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('products').orderByChild('title').equalTo(searchQuery)
```

the searchQuery variable is the the used string to search the database. this returns the list of products which the titles are equal to searchQuery.

```
searchQuery = 'hello';
title1 = 'hello';
title2 = 'hello there';
```

for now, only

```
searchQuery == title1;
searchQuery != title2;
```

but i also want this to be returned

```
searchQuery == title2;
```

is this possible in the way im using this for now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a `contains` query, but Firebase doesn't provide that. You can refine your actual query by looking for values that are `equalTo` or `endAt` or `startAt` (these methods are available to you as well). Making three requests is going to be costly, though.

If your database is not large and your data is not sensitive, I suggest fetching the whole data and making a client-side filter as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51456002/6696558).

Comment: i saw that a query like .equalsTo(query + "\nf8ff" will return everything what comes after the query text.  so query "hello"+"\nf8ff" will also return "hello there". 
so i thought "\nf8ff" + "there"+ "\nf8ff" would also return  "hello there" but this is not the case.

i dont know why such a basic query is not implemented :(

Comment: Where did you see that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46460825/firebase-querying-with-partial-string-match i found multiple posts using this method. the problem is you can only query "abc%" and not "%abc%" :/