# how to search document by name in firestore database like $regex in mongodb

Tags: node.js, regex, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

1. I am trying with this code to search the product by name in the database but it gives those data which is the same as in a database. so give a better solution.

Code:

```
 let response =  await db
            .collection("products")
            .where("productName", ">=", req.body.searchText)
            .where("productName", "<=", req.body.searchText + '\uf8ff')
            .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Firestore doesn't provide a solution for [full-text search](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search). As you can see, you can use [Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co/enterprise-search/search-applications), [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) or [Typesense](https://typesense.org/).

If you don't want such functionality, you can still use Firestore with a search that looks like this:

```
db.collection("products").orderBy("name")
    .startAt(req.body.searchText)
    .endAt(req.body.searchText + "\uf8ff");
```

If you're interested, for a better understanding, I recommend you read the following article:

- [How to filter Firestore data cheaper?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444)

Comment: Thanks for answering it's working but similar to earlier, but I want result incase sensetive let's suppose I search "pen" It should return result for "Pen" and "pen" As well but currently it match exact string

Comment: Queries in Firesroe are case-sensitive. To achieve what you want, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005587/firestore-database-query-ignore-case-case-insenstive-and-like-clause) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554793/are-cloud-firestore-queries-still-case-sensitive).

Comment: Hey Akshay. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: I will try this but I don't think It will fulfill my requirement. I will let you know.

Comment: Ok, give it a try and tell me if it works.