# How to link userids in 1v1 chat?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

For my 1v1 chat, I am trying to link my userids. I have created a global chat with my database looking like the image below.
[image]

This code allows me to search by userid on the firebase database and then pull up the private message html file where the two users will have the private chat.

```
            oneOnone.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
            ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {}, function (errorObject) {
                console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
            });
            ref.orderByChild("userId").on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
               console.log(snapshot.val().userId);
               console.log(searchId);
                if(searchId.value === snapshot.val().userId){
                    window.location.href = 'privatemessage.html';
                } 
            });
        });
```

I am leaning towards something like this for the one on one talk 
`var pmChat = database.ref('chat/' + userId);`

I would create a new reference and then add the first userid and then I would add the second userid or even the displayname.

How do I get id or displayname I am searching for and then have those two chatting and when each time a user searches, create a new node for each user's chat? And if the a user talks to the same person it goes back to that chat?

**Update**

I modified the code to look like this

```
oneOnone.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
        ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {}, function(errorObject) {
            console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
        });
        ref.orderByChild("userId").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
            console.log(snapshot.val().userId);
            if (searchId.value === snapshot.val().userId) {
                var currentUser = database.ref('chat').child(userId).child(searchId.value);
                var otherUser = database.ref('chat').child(searchId.value).child(userId);

                messageForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var user = auth.currentUser;
                    var userId = user.uid;
                    if (user.emailVerified) {
                        // Get the message the user entered
                        var message = messageInput.value;

                        var myPassword = "11111";
                        var myString = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, myPassword);

                        // Decrypt the after, user enters the key
                        var decrypt = document.getElementById('decrypt')

                        // Event listener takes input
                        // Allows user to plug in the key
                        // function will decrypt the message
                        decrypt.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            // Allows user to input there encryption password 
                            var pass = document.getElementById('password').value;

                            if (pass === myPassword) {
                                var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(myString, myPassword);
                                document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
                            }
                        });

                        // Create a new message and add it to the list.  
                        if (userId) {

                            currentUser.push({
                                    displayName: displayName,
                                    userId: userId,
                                    pic: userPic,
                                    text: myString.toString(),
                                    timestamp: new Date().getTime(), // unix timestamp in milliseconds

                                })
                                .then(function() {
                                    messageStuff.value = "";

                                })
                                .catch(function(error) {
                                    windows.alert("Your message was not sent!");
                                    messageStuff;
                                });
                        } else {
                            otherUser.push({
                                    displayName: displayName,
                                    userId: userId,
                                    pic: userPic,
                                    text: myString.toString(),
                                    timestamp: new Date().getTime(), // unix timestamp in milliseconds

                                })
                                .then(function() {
                                    messageStuff.value = "";

                                })
                                .catch(function(error) {
                                    windows.alert("Your message was not sent!");
                                    messageStuff;
                                });
```

I feel I am not grabbing the other userid because it is only the string value of the textbox.

```
var currentUser = database.ref('chat').child(userId).child(searchId.value);
 var otherUser = database.ref('chat').child(searchId.value).child(userId);
```

This is how I am creating the new references in the Firebase database.

Comment: DO NOT MAKE YOUR OWN SEARCH ALGORITHM! Use ref.orderByChild("userId").startAt(searchId).endAt(searchId+"\uf8ff")

Comment: Alright, what does the "\uf8ff" mean?

Comment: The \uf8ff character used in the query above is a very high code point in the Unicode range. Because it is after most regular characters in Unicode, the query matches all values that start with a b.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618953/how-to-do-a-simple-search-in-string-in-firebase-database

Comment: I end up getting this error when i changed it
Query.js:104 Uncaught Error: Query: First argument passed to startAt(), endAt(), or equalTo() cannot be an object.

Comment: Your query is an object. Only works with strings...