# Access child elements without knowing the parent

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Image showing database structure]

How can i access the circled email and password using android firebase.so far i have tried using the below code but it does not work.

```
Mref = new Firebase("https://blah blah/");

        Firebase objRef = Mref.child("Administrators");
        objRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Map<String, String>map=dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
                String password = map.get("password");
                String email = map.get("email");

                Log.d("email",email);
                Log.d("password",password);

                if(ed1.getText().toString().equals(password)&& ed2.getText().toString().equals(email)){
                    Intent intent=new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MapsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Log.d("password",password);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Wrong Credentials",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can accomplish a find/search this requirement. I suggest using the `email address` as your `key` for each of the driver object instead. I'd be interested to see if there was a way tho.. This might be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/a/34537728/1339516

Comment: Frank van Puffelen can you give me a snippet on how i could implement what is written in that link, to my code above

Comment: So i tried doing it like this but i get an error saying: Failed to bounce to type.    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot csnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        for (DataSnapshot ccsnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Map<String, String> map = ccsnapshot.getValue(Map.class);

                    String password = map.get("password");
                    String email = map.get("email");