# SELECT where document field contains the string in Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I select a document in my Firestore where the value of a field contains 'pp' ;
How to add option like `whereContains("title","pp")` in firestore ?
firestore added multiple where cause but we need "contains" also
   to improve search. Is there any alternate method available or firestore developers ignore it?

```
FirebaseFirestore db2 = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            db2.collection("products")
                    .whereEqualTo("cat","fruits")
                    .whereEqualTo("subcat","apple")
                    .whereEqualTo("blocked",false)
                    .whereContains("title","pp")
                    .get()


                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                for(int i=0;i<task.getResult().size();i++){
                                    Product product=task.getResult().getDocuments().get(i).toObject(Product.class);
                                    Log.d(TAG+"2", product.getTitle()+"");
                                }
                                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                  //  Log.d(TAG+"2", document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());

                                }
                            } else {
                                Log.w(TAG+"2", "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: You can take a look **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596610/is-it-possible-to-use-algolia-query-in-firestorerecycleroptions/49607796)**.

Answer (score 5):

Firestore has no method to search by substring.  Your options are to [mirror your data to a full text search engine](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search) such as Algolia, be clever about how you structure your data to support the specific kinds of queries that are similar to a substring search, or [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).