# How to search substring using firestore query in firestore document's field?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Android/Java:

In firestore document, I have a field "name" which have value `America`

I want to create a firebase query in the way that if I pass `ame` in that so it does return all the documents which have `ame` in the vale of their name field.

`firebaseFirestore.collection("country").whereContains("name", "ame");`

In short, I want to search/filter firestore data using substring.

Comment: There is no way to search for substrings in Cloud Firestore. The documentation recommends integrating with a third-party service like Algolia for that. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46568525, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50434226, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47133345, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47916173

Comment: Hey @VikasRana do mark the answer as correct, by clicking the V or tick mar like looking button next to the answer, as this helps the Stack Overflow readers and I'd appreciate that too. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

For this there is something that "MIGHT" help, it is called `array-contains` query. Know more about that here, https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html.

It is used in a way like this:

```java
collection("collectionPath").
    where("searchTermsArray", "array-contains", "term").get()
```

Otherwise there's also an option of using external service like [Algolia](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fulltext-search/README.md) or ElasticSearch for that.

Comment: firestore doesn't support where in java anymore. And my field data type is string not array.

Comment: You can make that an array or use Algolia as stated in the answer.