# Making a Firebase Realtime database searchable with algolia on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, searchview, algolia

I'm retrieving data from a Firebase Realtime Database on to Android Studio. I am looking to have a SearchView querying from the db. Thus far, I've only found info on how to implement Algolia and Firestore data for Android, or Algolia and Realtime Database for web (JS). 
Is it possible to have an Algolia search to query Firebase Realtime Database on Android? If not, what would be good alternatives?

Comment: That's definitely possible. There is no precanned documentation for it, but the approach is exactly the same as for Firestore. What step are you stuck on?

Comment: You can take a look **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596610/is-it-possible-to-use-algolia-query-in-firestorerecycleroptions/49607796)**. You should make your own attempt given the information in that answer, and ask another question if something else comes up. But remember, the principles are the same.