# How to query all childs values from child( firebase)

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to perform something like:

```
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("resources");
    Query firebaseSearchQuery =firebaseDatabase.child("tags").startAt(text).endAt(text+"\uf8ff");
```

Find matches with `text` in every `tags`'s childs values.
For me its:`"whopper", "burger", "king", "Whopper"`
[image]

How I can query and find matches?

Comment: Your current data structure makes it easy to find the tags for a resource. It does not however make it easy to find the resources for a tag. To allow that, you'll need to create an additional, inverse data structure that maps from tags back to the resources. For more on this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to find all children where values contains certain String.

***equalTo()***  Return items equal to the specified key or value depending on the order-by method chosen.

```
DatabaseReference rootReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference resources01Referense = rootReference.child("01").child("tags");
Query query = resources01Referense.orderByValue().equalTo(text+"\uf8ff");
```

Then query your data

[Link to do documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#read_and_write_lists)

Answer (score 0):

Your "tags" node is actually a Map, that contains four key-value pairs. Unfortunately, Firebase doesn't provide a way to search into such a structure using "startAt()" and "endAt()", which only works against a property of type String. What you need is some kind of a search feature. Unfortunately, Firebase does not support native indexing or search for text fields in database properties. However, to solve this issue, I recommend you check my answer from the following post:

- [Firebase Realtime Database Search by word in between the query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52789675/firebase-realtime-database-search-by-word-in-between-the-query/52789692)