# Search for users from a searchview in cloud firestore and filter them with recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

as the topic says. I want to be able to search for users by username using a searchview. I already showing all users in the recyclerview but I can't find a way to filter them. I using cloud firestore. Is it even possible? Or do I actually need a third part? All the guides and tutorials I have find so far is on firebase database..

Adapter Code.

```
public class AllUserAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<AllUsers, AllUserAdapter.AllUsersHolder> {

private OnItemClicklistener mOnItemClicklistener;
public AllUserAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<AllUsers> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AllUsersHolder holder, int position, @NonNull AllUsers model) {
    holder.textViewUsername.setText(String.valueOf(model.getName()));
    holder.textViewEmail.setText(model.getEmail());
    holder.setAvatar(model.getAvatar());

}

@NonNull
@Override
public AllUsersHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.all_user_list_display, viewGroup, false);
    return new AllUsersHolder(view);
}

class AllUsersHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView textViewUsername;
    TextView textViewEmail;
    ImageView imageViewAvatar;

    public AllUsersHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewUsername = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_user_username);
        textViewEmail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_user_userEmail);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && mOnItemClicklistener!= null){
                    mOnItemClicklistener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void setAvatar(String avatar){
        imageViewAvatar = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.all_user_profile_image);
        Picasso.get().load(avatar).into(imageViewAvatar);
    }
}

public interface OnItemClicklistener {
    void  onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot snapshot, int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClicklistener listener){
    mOnItemClicklistener = listener;
}
```

}

Userlist showing users with recylerview.

```
public class AllUserListFragment extends Fragment{
private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private CollectionReference allUsers = db.collection("users");

private AllUserAdapter mUserAdapter;

public AllUserListFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_user_list, container, false);


    Query query = allUsers;

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<AllUsers> recyclerOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<AllUsers>()
            .setQuery(query, AllUsers.class)
            .build();

    mUserAdapter = new AllUserAdapter(recyclerOptions);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.allUser_listView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mUserAdapter);

    mUserAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new AllUserAdapter.OnItemClicklistener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot snapshot, int position) {
            AllUsers allUsers = snapshot.toObject(AllUsers.class);
            String id = snapshot.getId();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("visit_user_id", id);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            AllUserProfileFragment fragment = new AllUserProfileFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mUserAdapter.startListening();
}
```

}

Comment: so you just need to filter the data set to the recyclerview right?

Comment: so do you want to use local filtering (filter your adapter) or filter the remote database?

Comment: @KevinKurien Yes, exactly! Lets say I have 10 users, all them is showing in the recyclerview ATM. But in my searchview I wanna type in lets say "B" and only showing users who's names start with an "B".

Comment: @pskink Im using the FirestoreRecyclerOptions<AllUsers> recyclerOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<AllUsers>()... So I guess filter the remote database?

Comment: so what you really want is to show a sublist in your adapter based on what you typed in a `SearchView`?

Comment: @pskink Exactly! I have a collection with users, then all users have a username. So when I search I wanna filter the recyclerview based on username from the SearchView!

Comment: @pskink Updated my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase does **not** support native indexing or search for text fields in database properties. Additionally, downloading an entire node to search for fields client-side isn't practical at all. To enable full text search of your Cloud FIrestore database, as is also specified in the [offical documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search) you should use a third-party search service like [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) or [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/).

**[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596610/is-it-possible-to-use-algolia-query-in-firestorerecycleroptions/49607796)** is an example on how it works with Cloud Firestore.

If there is no need for that, you should conisder using a query that look like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference brandsRef = rootRef.collection("brands");
brandsRef.orderBy("userName").startAt(searchName).endAt(searchName + "\uf8ff")
```

Comment: After some time yes, I didn't see the whole picture. I can now filter my recyclerview. Thanks

Comment: @PratikButaniAndroidDev No, is working as a `startingWith` query. It's the most simplest approach.

Comment: @AlexMamo Okay, So its like `startingWith` but doesn't like `LIKE` Qurery. Actually I wanted to find records which contains `developer` keyword anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

use TextWatcher and update your adapter accordingly

```
etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                String searchText = etSearch.getText().toString();
                arrUpdateList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < arrYourList.size(); i++) {
                    if (Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(searchText), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(arrYourList.get(i).title).find() {

                        arrUpdateList.add(arrYourList.get(i));
                    } else {
                    }
                }
                if (arrUpdateList.size() > 0) {
                    tvEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    lvSpecialOffer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bookCouponAdapter = new BookCouponAdapter(BookCouponListActivity.this, arrUpdateList);
        lvSpecialOffer.setAdapter(bookCouponAdapter);
                } else if (arrUpdateList.size() <= 0) {
                    lvSpecialOffer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tvEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried you're guys solutions, but I hadn't get it working.. I guess third part it is to make this work..

Thanks for the answers though. Cheers