# Query for upperCase child and RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 questions here.

1. How to make the search for query that second word?

ex: Big Apple.

When user search Apple, and it still will display the result.

I already make a research, most of the search query only search for the first word.

2. How to retrieve data from main child to relative view when we have 2 childs?

As you can see at the below, there are 2 types of database. What I found out is, we have to make new upperCase BUT in the main.

ex:

```
{
  "karangan" : {
    "karanganuid" : {
      "main": {
        "title": "Big Apple",
        "titleUpperCase": "BIG APPLE"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can we do like this? If we can, how to retrieve the data?

```
{
  "karangan" : {
    "karanganuid" : {
      "main" : {
        "title" : "Big Apple"
      },
      "upperCase" : {
        "titleUpperCase" : "BIG APPLE"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to make the search for query that second word?

Firebase realtime database does **not** support native indexing or search for text fields in database properties. So there is no `contains()` method for that.

Additionally, downloading an entire node to search for fields client-side isn't practical at all. To enable full text search of your database data, I recommend you to use a third-party search service like [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) or [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/).

If you consider at some point to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), please see my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596610/is-it-possible-to-use-algolia-query-in-firestorerecycleroptions/49607796)** where I have explained how it works with Cloud Firestore but in the same way you can use it with Firebase realtime database.