# How to implement in-app text search with firestore data?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, full-text-search

Hello friends once again!

I need to implement full text search in my android app and I am looking for the best way.

I have discovered few ways to do it,but I am asking for an advice which one will be the best and cause less problems. I have one collection fulldata, which has HTML text in it that I parse after query and then display it. I need to implement full text search in this collection.
I found recommended **Algolia text search** , but it is not exactly what I really need. **Or maybe I could search text from cache that caches data when connection is offline,based on firestore docs?**

***Is it possible to query all data and then store it in the ArrayList or maybe Array,or what will be the best option?***

Here is my viewModel that Queries whole collection.

```
public class DetailActivityViewModel extends ViewModel {

private final FirebaseListLiveData<Data> liveDataQuery;

public DetailActivityViewModel(String id) {
    liveDataQuery = new FirebaseListLiveData<>(Data.class, FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("fullData").whereEqualTo("mainId", id)
            .orderBy("order", Query.Direction.ASCENDING));
}
public FirebaseListLiveData<Data> getLiveDataQuery() {
    return liveDataQuery;
}
}
```

**And lastly my custom LiveData.**

```
public class FirebaseListLiveData<T> extends LiveData<List<T>> implements EventListener<QuerySnapshot> {

private Class<T> typeParameter;
private Query query;
private ListenerRegistration listenerRegistration;

public FirebaseListLiveData(Class<T> typeParameter, Query query) {
    this.typeParameter = typeParameter;
    this.query = query;
}
@Override
protected void onActive() {
    if (listenerRegistration == null) {
        listenerRegistration = query.addSnapshotListener(this);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onInactive() {
    if (listenerRegistration != null) {
        listenerRegistration.remove();
        listenerRegistration = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
    if (e == null) {
        if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null && !queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
            postValue(queryDocumentSnapshots.toObjects(typeParameter));
        } else {
            postValue(null);
        }
    } else {
        postValue(null);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596610/is-it-possible-to-use-algolia-query-in-firestorerecycleroptions/49607796)** out.

Comment: @AlexMamo well,algolia is not exactly what i need as I mentioned before