# How to add a search filter view in my RecyclerView that is connected in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

Here's the link of my reference: 
RecyclerView of Coding in Flow 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WR4QAiVuCw&t=43s

**Search Data**

```java
     private void searchData(String s) {
        String userInput = s;
        Query query = notebookRef.whereEqualTo("lastname", userInput);
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<NoteData> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<NoteData>()
                .setQuery(query, NoteData.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new NoteDataAdapter(options);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.idRecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: You can check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596610/is-it-possible-to-use-algolia-query-in-firestorerecycleroptions/49607796)** out.