# Does Firestore already support search?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

Just wandering if Firestore already support full-text search or does it still relay on Algolia? Documentation form my experience is not always up to date and I'm trying to use as less third party plugins as possible. If not, have you got this feature on your todo list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just wandering if Firestore already support full text search or does it still relay on Algolia.

No, it does not support full-text search.

> Documentation form my experience is not always up to date

The official documentation regarding the [full-text search in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search), is up to date and stands for Algolia.

For Android, please see my answer from the following question:

- [Is it possible to use Algolia query in FirestoreRecyclerOptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596610/is-it-possible-to-use-algolia-query-in-firestorerecycleroptions/49607796)

**Edit:**

Acording to the offical documentation regarding [mobile search](https://www.algolia.com/solutions/mobile-search/):

> We offer front end components for iOS, Android and mobile web. Each flavor respects the specific concepts, coding patterns and UX/UI best practices of its framework, so developers can quickly build state-of-the-art, mobile search and discovery experiences.

Comment: @Alex_Mamo Thanks for your quick response. What a shame. I'm working on web app. Have you got any idea if Algolia can be also implemented into a firestore function then?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. And yes, Algolia will also work for web apps.