# How to reduce the number of reads in a Firestore collection?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've learned how to use [pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741958/how-to-paginate-firestore-with-android) from a previous question of mine and I've implemented it in my a dictionary app for maritime terms. There are plenty of terms in the database.

The db is like so:

```
maritime_terms
  |- id
      |- term: "broad reach"
      |- details: "Sailing with the wind abaft the beam."
      |- etc
```

As in the docs I use:

```
db.collection("maritime_terms")
        .startAt(searchText)
        .endAt(searchText+ "\uf8ff")
        .limit(20);
```

When I start to search for example "broad reach" and I type the first letter `b`, I get 20 results. When I type the second letter, I get other 20 results. And so on. The problem is that for each letter I type I get 20 reads, so for a simple search I get from minimum of 100 reads to 150 or even more.

So far my app works great but I think it's expensive for a simple dictionary app. How can I reduce this huge number of reads?

Comment: Hi Johans. Good to hear that you are using my solution from that post but in this case, what do you mean through "plenty of terms", hundreds, thousands?

Comment: You are still here :))) I don't know yet, probably a few thousands. Can you help also here somehow?

Comment: I don't know if I can be much of a help in this case, since you are already using a `limit(20)` call. So you are already limiting the number of documents that you get from the database. A possible solution might be to reduce la that limit from 20 to less, let's say 10 or to as many as it fit in one screen. Beside that you can also try to implement Fogmeister's  solution might reduce the number of reads significantly.

Comment: However, I think I did something similar in the past and I think it might have a solution for that, so hold on, I will also write an answer for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Fogmeister's answer can help you reduce the number of reads significantly, I'll try to provide you another approach, but it will imply a change in your database structure. So this is what I would do.

First of all I will stop searching the `maritime_terms` collection in the way you do. Instead of that, I will create a document that will hold all the terms that you have in the database. Every term will be added in an array of terms. According to the length of the terms, it's possible to fit in one document all terms. I say that because the documents have limits. So there are some limits when it comes to how much data you can put into a document. According to the official documentation regarding [usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas):

> Maximum size for a document: 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)

As you can see, you are limited to 1 MiB total of data in a single document. When we are talking about storing text, you can store pretty much.

If all the terms do **not** fit in a single document, then you can simply create a document for each letter from the alphabet. Since you know what you search, it will be very easy to know what document to read. So take a look at the following schema:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- alphabetTerms (collection)
          |
          --- a (document)
          |   |
          |   --- aTerms: ["A-Term", "A-Term", "A-Term"]
          |
          --- b (document)
              |
              --- bTerms: ["B-Term", "B-Term", "B-Term"]
```

To get the `a` document, simply get a reference and make a `get()` call:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference aRef = rootRef.collection("alphabetTerms").document("a");
aRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
```

Even if the the `aTerms` is an array, when you make a `get()` call, you'll get it as a `List<String>` and **not** as an array. Then you can simply search that list of strings using:

```
termFromTheList.contains(searchedTerm);
```

One thing to note is that all terms must be unique in order to use this solution.

This solution it's a much better solution than the one you are using right now since it allow you to search a substring. For instance, if you want to search in `broad reach` for `reach`, this is not possible, unless you are using a third party service like [Algolia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49607796/5246885).

Once you find a match, get it and create a new query:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference maritimeTermsRef = rootRef.collection("maritime_terms");
Query searchQuery = maritimeTermsRef.whereEqualTo("term", searchedTerm);
searchQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
```

Using the solution above, you'll ending up having only one document read for finding the term in the document and one document read for displaying the details of the term.

> So you'll reduce the number of reads from <strike>150</strike> to only **2**.

Comment: Are you kidding me, 2 reads? :))) I thought to jump into another type of database because of the cost but sincerely you solved my problem more than I thought. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Btw, it will be unique since it's a dictionary and all terms are unique.

Comment: Sure Alex, you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The way to do this is to `debounce` the search.

This means that you can exploit the fact that a user will be typing at a certain number of key presses per second and delay the search a short while after each key press.

So for example if the users can be expected to type at a rate of 5 key strokes per second then after each key stroke start a timer of, say 0.3 seconds, only after this timer has expired will it start the search.

If the user taps another key in less than 0.3 seconds then scrap the timer and start it again for another 0.3 seconds.

This way, only once the user has stopped typing (or at least stoped typing for now) will the search actually be executed with the whole string.

However, this is not a change in Firestore. This would be a change in your client logic.

[You can read more about debouncing (and also throttling) at this link.](https://programmingwithmosh.com/javascript/javascript-throttle-and-debounce-patterns/)

**Example:**

1. User types `B`: start timer for 0.3 seconds.
2. User types `r` 0.2 seconds later: cancel timer, start a new timer for 0.3 seconds.
3. User types `o` 0.1 seconds later: cancel timer, start a new timer for 0.3 seconds.
4. 0.3 seconds elapsed with no typing. Start search with text `Bro`.

Comment: Thanks you for answering so quick. Never thought about that. I'll try to implement that and I let you know.

Comment: @JohansBormman no worries. I just provided a link for you to read some more about debouncing but I'm not sure what your client is written in so I can't provide any code examples.

Comment: I think I got the idea. Thanks for completing your answer.

Comment: Thanks again for answering my question. I will not use this solution since Alex has provided me an answer that can help me perform only two document reads but I'm sure this concept will be very helpful for me in the future.