# Algolia Search With Android and FireStore Data Base

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I want to implement the search bar in my android app, the backend language is Java, and the database is FireStore.

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596610/is-it-possible-to-use-algolia-query-in-firestorerecycleroptions/49607796)?

Answer (score 0):

Algolia has a [Kotlin Android client](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/android/?client=android), however, if you explicitly wanted to use Java you could implement your own client using the [API](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/rest-api/). The only downside to using the API is that there is no SLA provided if you are not using an Algolia-provided API Client.

To sync your data between Firestore and Algolia, there is an extension you can install which you can find more information on [here](https://www.algolia.com/developers/firebase-search-extension/).