# How to add full text search functionality in firestore in android studio?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, full-text-search, algolia

I know firebase doesn't support full text search by default. It suggests to use some 3rd party services.

I choose to go with Algolia but the problem is there's no documentation on how to integrate Algolia in android studio. There's a lot of tutorial for setting up Algolia with firebase for web apps.

Is there any better way or link to any tutorial to achieve full text search with Firestore in Android Studio.

I need it for an e-com android app similar to amazon.

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for tutorials are forbidden here, on StackOverflow.
However, maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596610/is-it-possible-to-use-algolia-query-in-firestorerecycleroptions/49607796) (which is some kind if old) will help. Here's another [resource](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6O6x-ZJp-10).

Answer (score 0):

The [Firebase extension](https://www.algolia.com/developers/firebase-search-extension/) will help you get your data from Firebase into an Algolia index. That's the same whether you're building a mobile or web application.

For building the mobile frontend Algolia recommends using the InstantSearch library. The steps for setting up InstantSearch in Android Studio are found [here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/getting-started/how-to/programmatically/android/#create-a-new-project-and-add-instantsearch-android)