# I want it to search anywhere between the text in firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code to search in the firebase database but it only searches from the start not in between.

```java
private void processSearch(String query) {
       Query query1 = databaseReference.child("posts").orderByChild("bookName").startAt(query).endAt(query+"\uf8ff");
       query1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
               for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                   AllPostItemHelper itemHelper = dataSnapshot.getValue(AllPostItemHelper.class);
                   itemHelper.setPostId(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                   allPostItemSearch.add(itemHelper);
               }
               AllPostItemAdapter allPostItemAdapter = new AllPostItemAdapter(allPostItemSearch,getContext());
               postThings.setAdapter(allPostItemAdapter);
           }

           @Override
           public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
               
           }
       });
   }

}
```

Comment: Aside from my answer, since you're using Java, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FilterFirestoreResults). It's for Firestore, but you can simply adapt it to the Realtime Database.

Answer (score 0):

> only search from the starting not in between

That's expected behavior since you are performing a call to [Query#startAt()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#startAt(java.lang.String)) which:

> Creates a query constrained to only return child nodes with a value greater than or equal to the given value, using the given orderBy directive or priority as default.

However, if you need to search for a substring, please note that this is not possible. You can only perform queries that match a string that starts with a specific string or starts with a range of strings.

If you think to download an entire node to search for fields client-side, please note that this solution isn't practical at all. To enable a full-text search for your Firebase Realtime Database data, I recommend you use a third-party search service like [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) or [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/).

If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), please see the following example:

- [Is it possible to use Algolia query in FirestoreRecyclerOptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596610/is-it-possible-to-use-algolia-query-in-firestorerecycleroptions/49607796)

To see how it works with Cloud Firestore but in the same way, you can use it with Firebase Realtime Database.

Comment: Hey Rahul. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?