# Firestore firebase Android search and update query

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update a field of existing document in my collection in **FireBase Firestore**. I want to search that document using one of its field. 
My collection name is "complaints", 
My document's structure looks like --

```
complainant_Name: "XYZ"
complaint_Details : "some random details"
e_Mail: "xyz@gmail.com"
id: 5
phone_No: "1234567890"
```

I want to search documents and if "id" field of a document is say 5, I want to update it say change "complainant_Name" field to "ABC". How to write the code for this query in java android? I couldn't find any code source which tells how to update after searching in **Firebase Firestore**.

Comment: I think, this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537369/how-to-search-for-a-value-in-firebase-android]

Comment: @ATIKFAYSAL You provided a link that explains how to do this in Firebase realtime database while the OP is asking for Cloud Firestore, which is a different product.

Comment: I want to query on Firebase Firestore , not Firebase realtime database. The link you are providing is for the Firebase realtime database. And also I want to update as well (not only search as mentioned in link).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference complaintsRef = rootRef.collection("complaints");
complaintsRef.whereEqualTo("id", 5).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Map<Object, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("complainant_Name", "ABC");
                complaintsRef.document(document.getId()).set(map, SetOptions.merge());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

After using this code, the property `complainant_Name` will hold the value of `ABC`.

Comment: Thank you!! a minor mistake with rootRef.coolection("complaints"); should be  rootRef.collection("complaints");

Comment: @AdiAzarya Thanks for the typo ;)