# Update a document in firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I would like the update a document in Firebase. The problem is that you can only update a specific field?

I would like to do something like this:

```
fs.collection("users").document(user.id).update(user)
```

The problem is that Kotlin forces to put a field in update, like this:

```
fs.collection("users").document(user.id).update("firstname", user)
```

But I don't want that, I want to update the whole document with my model not a field.

Comment: What node version are you using?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using the following line of code:

```
fs.collection("users").document(user.id).update("firstname", user)
```

You'll be able to update only a single property. If you want to update multiple properties, please use the following lines of code:

```
fs.collection("users").document(user.id).update("firstname", "John",
                                                "lastname", "Smith",
                                                "age", 25)
```

If you want to update a document using an object of your `User` class, please use the `set()` method instead of `update()`, like in the following line of code:

```
fs.collection("users").document(user.id).set(user)
```

You can also use a `Map` to update a document, as explained in my answer from the following post:

- [Firestore firebase Android search and update query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53378868/firestore-firebase-android-search-and-update-query)