# CRUD flutter firebase & UPDATING rather then creating new

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i have a function that creates and add new data to the cloud firestore! i want the function to check if the documents already exist, if so update them otherwise create them!
i do not know how its done. can someone help me with this please!
thank you all in advance.
this is the function.

```
static void createPostMonday(Post post) {
    postsRef.document(post.authorId).collection('Monday').add({

      'alOne':post.alOne,
      'altwo':post.alTwo,
      'althree':post.alThree,
      'alFour':post.alFour,
      'alFive':post.alFive,
      'alSix':post.alSix,
      'beOne':post.beOne,
      'beTwo':post.beTwo,
      'beThree':post.beThree,
      'beFour':post.beFour,
      'beFive':post.beFive,
      'beSix':post.beSix,
      'likes': post.likes,
      'authorId': post.authorId,
      'timestamp': post.timestamp,
    });
  }
```

Comment: What you have now always adds a new document using a random document ID regardless of what already exists.  What condition do you intend to use to determine if some document already exists?  You will need to be specific about this, otherwise you will have a very hard time making this work.

Comment: hi Doug. the classes are based on activities that my users get to set weekly! in other words i am looking for a solution that updates the same documents  set for monday activities after the users set them once  instead of creating new document when users wants to upload next weeks monday activities! @DougStevenson thank you for responsing

Comment: You can check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59905856/i-need-to-update-document-if-exists-otherwise-create)** out.

Comment: hi @AlexMamo. thank you for your answer! i checked out your solution and i am having a hard time implementing it in my code! can you help me understand better? thank you in advance

Comment: i am getting error saying (the method setData isn't defined for the class CollectionReference!     postsRef.document(post.authorId).collection('Monaday').setData.     what am i doing wrong? anyone can help?