# Why do we set the parameter in HashMap to object when sending data to firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, hashmap

I am watching a video to create a simple app(just to practice concepts) where the user enters the title and their thoughts. This data will get sent to Firestore.

However, I was confused on the part where I send data through a HashMap:

```java
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put(STRING_TITLE, title);
data.put(STRING_THOUGHTS, thoughts);
```

The title and thought are basically just the string values of the user's input for the title and thought.

```java
String thoughts = edtThoughts.getText().toString().trim();
String title = edtTitle.getText().toString().trim();
```

After that, all I'm doing is just passing it into the journalRef: `journalRef.set(data)` where journalRef is just the DocumentReference of my database:

```java
private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference journalRef = db.collection("Journal").document("MyThoughts");
```

My question is: **Why do we pass data as `Map<String, Object>` instead of `Map<String, String>`. Isn't the title and thoughts just the user's input as a String value?**

Edit:

Also, when I go to Firestore, why does it show the thoughts and title as a String rather than an Object(which was declared in the HashMap)?

[image: Hovers over data, shows string]

Thanks!

Comment: `getText()` already returns a `String`. You don't need to call `toString()` on a `String`.

Comment: You can set it to anything you like that compiles for you. The actual parameter of `set(data)` is `Object`. Once it gets inside that method your genericisation is lost anyway.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Firestore document, field names are always precisely Strings, while the values are objects. It doesn't really matter if you want to add a String, a Boolean, a Number, or any kind of object that is a [supported data type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types), all can be considered objects. The number one rule in Java is that everything is an object. So it doesn't matter what you add to the database, Firestore will always save the data according to its data type. To answer your question:

> Why do we pass data as Map<String, Object> instead of Map<String, String>?

You need to pass the data according to the operation you need to perform. If you want to add data to the database using the [set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#set(java.lang.Object)) method, then you can use `Map<String, String>` and this is because this method requires an argument of type Object. However, if you want to perform an update operation using the [update()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#update(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)) method, please note that you **cannot** use Map<String, String>, because the method requires a `Map<String, Object>`. Besides that, when you want to perform an update, you can pass different types of objects as values, and get the fields updated accordingly. So you can always [update multiple fields at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56608046/update-a-document-in-firestore).

> Isn't the title and thoughts just the user's input as a String value?

Yes, it is. If you only want to add the title and thoughts using set(), then you can use Map<String, String>, otherwise, for an update operation, you need to use Map<String, Object>.

And to answer your edited question:

> Also, when I go to Firestore, why does it show the thoughts and title as a String rather than an Object(which was declared in the HashMap)?

It will always display the values according to the values you have added. In the Firebase Console, there is no representation for an object other than the one for a map. Besides that, behind the scene, there is an [instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/pattern-matching-instanceof-operator.html) verification for each object you add. So if if you pass a String, that Object will always be saved as a String and not in any other way.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your above example as `Map<String, String>` because of the simple data you are putting in it.  But a more advanced example might have you put a deeper structured object into Firestore, so use of `Map<String, Object>` is more appropriate.  Firestore is a "document store database" where a document is a HashMap.  The elements within that hash are name/value pairs, where the name is a string and the value can be: String, Boolean, Number, Timestamp, Array, (Hash)Map, Geolocation.

So declaring `data` as `HashMap<String, Object>` is more correct because of what *could* go into it.

Comment: Thanks! Please look at the edit I've made to my question.

Comment: When I hover over the data, it shows it as a String. Any idea why this may be so? Thanks.