# Flutter: How can i search realtime database in a TextField?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have gone through multiple searching tutorials and articles but unfortunately i couldn't find any search method that can support Realtime database logic search in flutter, so is there any simple way to search Reealtime database in a TextField?

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:idevice_me/providers/project_provider.dart';
import 'package:idevice_me/screens/user_detail_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';



class HomeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeWidget({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeWidget> createState() => _HomeWidgetState();
}

class _HomeWidgetState extends State<HomeWidget> {

  
  var _isInit = true;
  
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies(){
    if(_isInit){
       Provider.of<ProjectProvider>(context, listen: false).readData();
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

   

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  TextEditingController searchData =  TextEditingController();
  var dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
  
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream:  dbRef.child('users').onValue,
      builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          //----------------------------
          //USERID comes from here
          //----------------------------
         final userSnapshot = snapshot.data!.snapshot.children.toList();
          return Column(
            children: [
             const SizedBox(height: 20,),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0, left: 15.0),
                child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Search',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14,color: Colors.grey.shade400,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade300),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                              borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                            ),
                            floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
                          ),
                          key: const ValueKey('search'),
                            
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,

                            controller: searchData,
                          
                        ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10,),
              // ignore: deprecated_member_use
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  setState(() {
                    
                  });
                }, 
              child: const Text('Search'),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.black,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
              ),
              const Divider(),
                     const SizedBox(height: 20,),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: userSnapshot.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, i)=> Column(
                    children: [
                      // ignore: sized_box_for_whitespace
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: (){
                          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                            UserDetailScreen.routeName, 

                            //--------------------------------------
                            //USERID should be here through snapshot
                            //--------------------------------------

                            arguments: userSnapshot[i].key.toString(),
                            );
                        },
                        
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            ListTile( 
                              leading: const Icon(Icons.person),
                              title: Text(userSnapshot[i].child('username').value,),
                              subtitle: Text(userSnapshot[i].child('email').value,),
                              trailing: Text(userSnapshot[i].child('phone').value.toString()),
                              onTap: (){
                                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                                  UserDetailScreen.routeName,
                                  arguments: userSnapshot[i].key.toString()
                                  );
                              },
                            ),
                            const Divider(),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                  ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        }
        return const Center(child: Text('There is something wrong!'),);
      },
      );

      
  }

 
    
  }
```

Hope someone did the Realtime database package search before :(.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

"search" is a really broad term, so it's unclear what exactly you mean to do. But the first thing to realize is that Firebase Realtime Database has quite limited query support (documented [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/usage#querying)) and they are nowhere near SQL's `LIKE` clause, let alone the capabilities of a dedicated full-text search engine. If you want more advanced features than Firebase support, consider using a solution that supports those features better either in addition to Firebase, or as an alternative.

Also see:

- [How to perform sql "LIKE" operation on firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506531/how-to-perform-sql-like-operation-on-firebase)
- [Firebase and indexing/search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559191/firebase-and-indexing-search)
- [How to search for a value in firebase Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537369/how-to-search-for-a-value-in-firebase-android/34537728#34537728)