# Setting up Flashlight on Heroku for ElasticSearch with new Firebase

Tags: ios, node.js, heroku, elasticsearch, firebase

My goal is to connect Firebase with ElasticSearch for indexing so that I can implement "like" queries when searching usernames in my iOS app. From what I've read this is the best solution, and I want to tackle it this way early in order to be scalable instead of brute-forcing it.

To achieve this, I'm trying to deploy the [flashlight](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight) app that Firebase developers have provided for us onto a Heroku, but I'm confused on how to go about doing it. Please correct me where I'm wrong, I'm fairly new to the Heroku ecosystem, ElasticSearch, and nodejs.

I currently have a Heroku account, and have the toolbelt and nodejs/npm installed on my computer (Mac).  I've run the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/firebase/flashlight
cd flashlight
heroku login
heroku create
heroku addons:add bonsai
heroku config
```

(I was able to get my bonsai url successfully with the heroku config command)

The next step is

```
heroku config:set FB_NAME=<instance> FB_TOKEN="<token>"
```

But I don't really understand what FB_NAME (my guess is Firebase app name, but is that the name of my app? or with the letters/numbers following it due to the new Firebase setup where it's no longer `app_name.firebaseio.com` but `app_name-abc123.firebaseio.com`) and what is FB_TOKEN? (is it a key or something in my plist I download?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get your `FB_NAME` (it's basically your Firebase project's ID):

1. Go to `Project Settings`
2. Go to `General` tab
3. Copy your `Project ID`

[image]

To get your `FB_TOKEN`:

1. Go to your [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com)
2. Select the project that is associated with your Firebase project
3. Go to `Credentials` page
4. Create a new `API Key` or choose if you have an appropriate one already

Note:
You can also set (and see) those variables in you Heroku project (if you don't want to set it from the terminal). To do that:

1. Go to your Heroku project's `Settings` page
2. Click on the `Reveal Config Variables` button

Good luck.

Comment: I can't figure out where to find the data to fill FIREBASE_ADMIN_USER and FIREBASE_ADMIN_PASS as heroku buildpack for firebase suggest: https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/casetext/heroku-buildpack-firebase could you help me?

Comment: @rubdottocom I did not tied that buildpack it but I believe they should be your login credentials to your Firebase account. Can you try and share the result?

Comment: Hi @MustafaBerkayMutlu how about the configuration of "config.js"? stated on https://github.com/firebase/flashlight

Comment: @prettyitgirl.com As the config.js file says "At a minimum, you must set FB_URL and Paths to Monitor. Everything else is optional, assuming your ElasticSearch server is at localhost:9200." You must edit those (FB_URL and Paths) attributes in the config.js then deploy your app to Heroku. Flashlight reads the remaining variables from Heroku and uses defaults if it can't find those variables.