# Does Firebase provide us all queries like Parse Database for Android?

Tags: parse-platform, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does Firebase provide all [queries](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#queries) like parse database for Android?

Like `wherecontaiendIn()`, `Equalto()` etc?

Comment: They dont have query .withinRange() - geolocation...but you can always build your own... It does nt know why you ask here and just wont check the documentation though...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506531/how-to-perform-sql-like-operation-on-firebase

Answer (score 2):

Pretty theoretical question. Try looking in their documentation: [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/)

Firebase allows custom queries and some pre-defined methods such as:

> Query:     startAt(boolean value, String key) Create a query constrained
>   to only return child nodes with a value greater than or equal to the
>   given value, using the given orderBy directive or priority as default,
>   and additionally only child nodes with a key greater than or equal to
>   the given key.

And many others such as:

> **startAt(boolean value)**
>
> nodes with a value greater than or equal to the given value, using the
>   given orderBy directive or priority as default.
>   **startAt(double value, String key)**
>
> Create a query constrained to only return child nodes with a value
>   greater than or equal to the given value, using the given orderBy
>   directive or priority as default, and additionally only child nodes
>   with a key greater than or equal to the given key.Create a query constrained to only return child

Check their complete database references here: [Firebase Database API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/package-summary)

Check all queries functions: [Firebase Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query)

Or you can check their complete API here: [API Reference Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/)