# Firebase App Search Feature - Query Using String Regex

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am porting an app over from Parse to Firebase and I used to be able to query using `matchesRegex` and putting the search into `"(?i)\(searchBar.text!)"`. By doing this, the user could search "p" and the database would return (for example) "person", "People", "pot", etc.

I can't seem to find a way to query like this using Firebase that allows a user to search part of a String and Firebase looks for the substring within the database.

I am using:

```
databaseReference.child("Schools").queryOrderedByKey().queryEqualToValue("(?i)\(searchBar.text!)").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

    for childSnapshot in snapshot.children {

        print("SANP \(childSnapshot)")

    }

    }) { (error) in

        print(error)

    }
```

If I do this, nothing is printed. I know the code above works if I search for a specific value that is character-for-character the same as it is in the database.

**How can I search using parts of a String within the Firebase database?**

Comment: There is no built-in support for regular expression or LIKE "%...%" matching in Firebase queries. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38538863/firebase-query-containing-value, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38473967/is-there-a-way-to-do-regex-query-or-return-results-that-contain-specific-text-in, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559191/firebase-and-indexing-search, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506531/how-to-perform-sql-like-operation-on-firebase, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38566949/does-firebase-provide-us-all-queries-like-parse-database-for-android

Comment: So basically if your user types some random letters you want to show all the  schools who have those letters in their school name, right(something like google search)?

Comment: @Dravidian Exactly! Like a google search. Or, say you are searching a person on Facebook, if you type in an A, it will show all friends that have an a or A in it.

Comment: @DanLevy what you are asking is called a recommendation engine. Its kinda of Machine Learning (Artificial Intelligence:https://www.quora.com/How-exactly-is-machine-learning-used-in-recommendation-engines) if you are looking for big chunk of DB like Google, But for small database i can give you a solution But efficiency might be a problem there...