# Firebase: Structure data for multilingual searchterms

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, denormalization

We have a multilingual IOS and Android Parse app which we are migrating to Firebase.

Users can change the locale of the app and so they can also search with words in their own language.

In Parse we use the regex query on a `String` field (ex. "auto, car, coche, 汽车, carro, voiture) of the objects.

IOS:

```
query!.whereKey("stringIndex", matchesRegex: searchTerm.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()))
```

Android:

```
query.whereMatches("stringIndex", searchText.trim().toLowerCase());
```

How can we do this in firebase and how can we structure the data to get the search result we need?

Thanks in advance!

Updated

The only possibility we have for now is structuring our keywords-data like this

[image]

Our only concern is if firebase, can handle this when you have 100,000 keywords when a user does an offline search?

Comment: Please be aware of the use of the formatting option as it helps users read your question better

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39606627/firebase-app-search-feature-query-using-string-regex