# Firebase 3.0 Query of multiple fields / Query.contains() alternative for Firebase 3.0

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm just wondering how to query this particular type of data.

[sample set of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HoFk.png)

Basically I would want to query a name which contains a particular string in both firstname and lastname. For example if i search the string "Ani"
both names Danilo Marino and Ian Danico Marino should show up.

I was thinking adding of a synthetic index combining firstName and lastName however .contains() from the old query api doesnt seem to be included in the new API.

Client side filtering might be out of the question since i might have multiple names numbering to tens of thousands.

Comment: I don't think this use-case has ever been possible with the Firebase API. The [2.x Query class](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/) didn't have a `contains()` method either. What `.contains() ` method are you referring to?

Comment: The answer has always been to use an external search engine, such as described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506531/how-to-perform-sql-like-operation-on-firebase