# Search a Substring in Firebase

Tags: android, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I want to implement a SearchView for my App wich is connected to Firebase Database.

[image: Database Structure]

And now I want to Search for a Name, like in the Picture "Jay No" and add it to a ListView, but I do not want to Search for a specific name, I want to search for Example for: "Jay" and then I want to receive every name in the Database which contains "Jay"...

How can I implement it?

Comment: Firebase Database queries do not support "contains" queries. You can get names that *are* Jay or that *start with* Jay, but not names that *contain* Jay. If such queries are necessary for your app, you should consider using another service that supports them. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506531/how-to-perform-sql-like-operation-on-firebase

Comment: This is a fairly common problem. I don't think this should have been marked as a duplicate, even though one could construct their solution by the older question's answers.