# How can I achieve equivalent of .contains(SomeText) in Firebase Real time Database Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to let my users search for some contents in my Firebase real time Database. The problem is that Firebase Query only lets me search/filter results with endAt() and startAt(). For Example Let's say my User searches for "rro" , then my searchview should generate suggestions as "Arrow" (after looking in my database if it finds entry with Arrow).

I am able to put suggestions in searchview myself but the problem is .startAt() and .endAt() cannot achieve / or find anything if "rro" is provided. I want filter like .contains();

How can I achieve this in Firebase for Android?

Comment: The Firebase Database is not a full-text search engine. If you need such capabilities, you'll have to add another component for that. Have a look at Kato's answer here for one option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506531/how-to-perform-sql-like-operation-on-firebase

Comment: I don't want to use Firebase cloud functions because I currently have no good knowledge of node.js .  Is there any other way out. A effective and fast

Comment: It'll require an external text search engine. Maybe somebody else knows an easier option, but it's unlikely (this question is asked regularly and the one I linked is the de-facto answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a better answer for this situation that doens't requiere creating a special structure:

> 

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").orderByChild("LastName").startAt(queryText).endAt(queryText+"\uf8ff");
```

> The character \uf8ff used in the query is a very high code point in
>   the Unicode range (it is a Private Usage Area [PUA] code). Because it
>   is after most regular characters in Unicode, the query matches all
>   values that start with queryText.
>
> In this way, searching by "Fre" I could get the records having "Fred,
>   Freddy, Frey" as value in LastName property from the database.

The original answer is by Rizwan Khan.
Link: https://www.quora.com/How-would-you-search-a-Firebase-Realtime-Database-with-a-substring

Comment: Sergio, thanks for the answer. It's ok, but share pls links when you quotes any

Comment: @YuriyTsarkov sorry, didn't know if it was ok to publish a link to another page, I'll add it.

Comment: How would I go about finding "Walder Frey" using "Fre" as search term? Or "Mad Freddy has blue glasses"? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make structure like this

```
- objects
  - UID1:Arrow
  - UID2:Rowboat
  - UID3:Bow
- searchable
  - arrow
    - UID1
  - rrow
    - UID1
  - row
    - UID1
    - UID2
  - ow
    - UID1
    - UID2
    - UID3
  - w
    - UID1
    - UID2
    - UID3
  - rowboat
    - UID2
  - owboat
    - UID2
  - wboat
    - UID2
  - boat
    - UID2
  - oat
    - UID2
  - oa
    - UID2
  - a
    - UID1
    - UID2
  - bow
    -UID3
```

Then its easy to search, just use a Query like

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("searchable").orderByKey().startAt(input).endAt(input+"~");
```

When you create object like arrow you must use a .updateChildren() where you add the entries in searchable aswell. Also when arrow changes name you must update in searchable aswell, and I recommend convert all to lowercase, both your search text and the object names in searchable.

Comment: This is not what I want, I have a structure similar to this and have a node called searchable with keys as titles and values as url to body. This would make the searchable node filled with many keys, I don't want that.. I need optimization and as effective as it can be...
The Title will be generated by end user so he/she may give a title like "The King and the Prince" then there will be so many keys for this note.. (about 17Combination3) that would be ineffective and will occupy heavy on my database..

Comment: This would be a workaround true, but only if you have a few records, and as you can see in the example, you only have 3 UIDs, and yet more that 10 times the records you started with. What if you have 1000, or 100.000 UIDs? This solution is not viable.