# Nested list query in Firebase using Ionic3

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I have the following structure in Firebase.

```
user
    |- 111
          |-name: 'ABC'
    |- 222
          |-name: 'XYZ'
    |- 333
          |-name: 'AMN'
```

Now can I write a query in Angular2 in Ionic3 which will only give the users whose name contains letter 'A' or I have to fetch the entire list and filter.

Comment: Firebase Database queries cannot filter for values that **contain** a certain substring. They can only do **starts with**. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506531/how-to-perform-sql-like-operation-on-firebase

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874050/nested-list-query-in-firebase-using-ionic3

Comment: Hi Frank, I think the function you want to say in startAt() but this one does not really give a result which starts with some character. Hi Mohamad, You have entered this thread link by mistake I think. Please provide the correct link is possible