# Android Firebase- How to Query using Contains()?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to Query a value in the Firebase Database not by a specific value, but something it contains.

For example:

```
Database:
      -users: "user1, user2, user3"
```

I want to query user2, but since it is with other values, I cannot query it. 
Is there a way to query using contains()?

Thanks

Comment: post your code that you tried so far, and post your firebase db structure

Comment: There is no built-in operator to do a query with a `contains()` operation. The most common approach is to use a third-party full-text search engine for this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506531/how-to-perform-sql-like-operation-on-firebase