# android firebase substring query

Tags: android, firebase

i am looking for a firebase query to get all the nodes that lets say they have a title.
  i want to get all the nodes that their title contains a specific string .
like if i say the string is  "he"  i get the nodes with the title "he is alone"
"hello mother" ....ect 
i already know the query to get the node that have a title that is equal to the String that u entred in the query
`

Query query = reference.child("issue").orderByChild("id").equalTo(0);`

i  want to get ( a part of String or contain).
 thanks in advance ( sorry for my bad english)

Comment: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/01/queries-part-2-advanced-searches-with.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform sql "LIKE" operation on firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506531/how-to-perform-sql-like-operation-on-firebase)