# How to use LIKE in react-firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

I can't figure out how to use the `LIKE` operator on Firestore with `React-redux-firebase`.

I would like something similar to this:

```
Select * from countries where name LIKE %xico% //RESULT = Mexico
```

I tried the following:

```
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase'

var name = 'xico'

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),firestoreConnect([{ collection : 'countries', orderBy :'name',startAt:name,endAt:name+'\uf8ff'}])　
)(Dashboard);
```

But, it does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/22506531/2873538

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform sql "LIKE" operation on firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506531/how-to-perform-sql-like-operation-on-firebase)

Comment: I am looking for a way to perform on the "react-redux-firebase"module.

Comment: There are no substring searches in Firebase (any platform) so you can't directly do that. Read the info provided in the above links for a solution. As an alternative, you can check out [ElasticStore](https://github.com/acupofjose/elasticstore).